# Google APIs JS File

Tags: javascript, api, e-commerce

In building a Google Commerce Search search form, one of the pieces of code Google instructed us include was located at this address:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/googleapis/0.0.4/googleapis.min.js

I'm getting a javascript error that seems to be emanating from this javascript file and I was wondering if this is the latest version of said javascript file?  If not, can someone direct me as to where the latest version of this google api JS file lies?

P.S. I have been unable to get any conclusion from Google that this is the correct, most-up-to-date version of the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking after google search API - this is the location to find the latest:
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview

In case you need some other APIs checkout their new location at:
https://developers.google.com/ you will have there a list of all the (many) APIs.